# Amazon SES Verified Identities Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES and found that there's a limit on verifying identities i.e. 1000 emails (senders) per account.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html#limits-sender-recipient

My application is sending around million emails everyday, and I am creating email identites, but now I am coming near to 1000.

What's the best work around to solve this issue? Or is there any chance Amazon will increase it?

Comment: Why are you creating 1000+ email identities per day? Verification is only required for the "sending" entity (and also for Sandbox sends).

Comment: Thats not per day limit, thats total limit. My application allows user to send email from their name and email, so I ll need it.

Comment: 10 Laks = 1.000.000 ????

Answer (score 1):

Amazon will not increase that for now. You can:

1.- Use 1.000 Verified Senders for each SES region, which totals: 3.000, the more regions Amazon adds to SES, the more Verified Senders you'll have. Today Amazon has SES available on the following regions: Virginia, Oregon,  Ireland.

[image]

2.- Create another Amazon AWS account, so you have 3.000 more Verified Senders available.

3.- **Best approach**, not yet available from AWS: create separate AWS accounts for each of your users using AWS API, and then create a user for that AWS account with a Policy which enables that user to use the SES API.

**Be careful** when allowing so many senders use your SES account. If any of them does malpractice, Amazon AWS team, will right away cancel your AWS account or limit your SES sending capabilities.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on technic #1 - is it just about connecting to different endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do this!

First of all, SES is designed to be a "few senders to many recipients" service, not a "many (untrusted) senders to many recipients".

Second, sending emails on behalf of others is not a good practice; instead, use your own verified sender and add the user as a Reply-To: address. In this way, hitting the Reply will send the email to the correct person and you can actually use email signing (DKIM, etc.).

For example:

```
From: <mailer@yourdomain.com>
Reply-To: <user@domain.org>
Subject: ...
```

Comment: Just trying to udnerstand how https://emailoctopus.com/ using it as they must have more than 1000 customer (sender)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if sendgrid sets a limitation on sender addresses, I couldn't find anything on any limits for that. They may be a good alternative for your use case. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/sender_address.html

Comment: OP specifically asked for SES solution only. Sendgrid is NOT a good alternative to SES. It's for getting started maybe, or people who are not technical enough. It's quite expensive & doesn't offer as much customization as OP is asking for.